# Make a vega heatmap with means of binned values

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

Let's start from this example:

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/heatmap/

[image]

This is a glimpse of the underlying data:

```
date    pressure    temperature wind
2010-01-01T01:00:00 1016.6  4   3.8
2010-01-01T02:00:00 1016.6  3.9 3.8
2010-01-01T03:00:00 1016.7  3.8 3.8
2010-01-01T04:00:00 1016.7  3.8 3.7
2010-01-01T05:00:00 1016.5  3.7 3.8
2010-01-01T06:00:00 1016.4  3.7 3.8
```

In the above figure, the color of each cell in the heatmap represents the value of `temperature` from a single row in the data table.

Suppose we want to change the display, so that the color of each cell in the heatmap represents the **average of multiple rows** in the data table?

For example, suppose we want to apply binning to both the x-axis and to the y-axis.

For the y-axis, we would create 3 bins:

- 6am-11am, 12pm-6pm, 7pm-12am

For the x-axis, we would create 12 bins:

- one bin for each month

Then, the heatmap would have 3 rows and 12 columns, and the color of each cell in the heatmap would correspond to the average of temperature values in the corresponding bin.

Questions:

1. How would you do this with vega? Can we use a `transform` to accomplish this task?
2. Should we use another javascript library to do the binning first, and then pass the result to vega?
3. Could you share a code snippet or suggest a library for efficient 2d binning (e.g., for a million items with continuous x,y positions)?
4. Suppose some of the bins correspond to no data (0 rows in the data table). Can we skip drawing them entirely? Or color them with a background color?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Vega or Vega-Lite?

Comment: Jake, I'm still learning, so any tips for how to approach this with either vega or vega-lite would be great! Do you think one or the other is more appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transform `calculate` to group them in your bands using ternary conditions and create a new field as `timeGroup` and then use it in your y-axis as done below or in

Try it in the editor: [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQSBpjYQaALzhpQUOZiQ1ZENCBxIAJpeNlFITAE8cO9ADM69gE5wN2tJheDHAAvkoA7jSW9GgAbAAM8UrwNGRYaACMYknmVjaydqiggnBumJliSl6p6agJSkxs2GwIaGJhIJZIhrogDF6CZl2GnHDdmCX84WP0cF78MGz9go78smxeyIIQlFAQxPZuG8jlRQ7OriB7B0oWXhCuoMOXzyAh70qBSCZHm2gA2nokIIoAxBN1LggDDAABTDBgISjPACU9iQpnQUGIABEIW8FECQWC8ehVLAlvc4d0EUiIailOizIt+hBcZgdGFCaDweyzPEAAQAHn58MRzPubLg-IAZNKRdSxRTWRChfyAOz8gD8-IA5Bl+UgEPz+PzYgaEDrUKbVaLKOLleyZXLbfbJaqMgBmLW6jWG438jIAJn5OAt-KtQZtCrtSrdsvlmBprpVwoyAE5vXqQ0aTWbQ5afdn-ZHDTq0RiHDQEHAAOJeJY4fFc4m89C2zBV2v1hg4fkAXj7uv1ftz5p13oFVvbnbrDf7g51vpzAeD+e9+qn0Y71dnPfnQ6Lo7X2uDVo95bMG0scwASt8ANZvAC6Sjgsn0+UKoEcvQ8cEElhmNuXYNvYTguJeXj5MC9gyF4pygH+AGQdeXh3rIj5KFecxDL4UBvp+bwdAAHr+ND-oBbZ4p8FwocYMGfJ2ACqsieOgUKyDEShwacshgoIHwgOCjg4aggIgMgXiPmc4GXD4UDlB0b4frYZGCIMZxIZRDiIC4XjUj4YG0egACODDfB2hgdqQaJkGQPgUK2EljPI7whE+IRAA)

Here's the figure:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "autosize": {"contains": "padding", "type": "fit", "resize": true},
  "width": 600,
  "height": 150,
  "padding": {"left": 15, "right": 60, "bottom": 5},
  "data": {
    "url": "data/seattle-weather-hourly-normals.csv",
    "format": {"type": "csv", "parse": {"date": "date"}}
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "month(datum.date)", "as": "cvDate"},
    {"calculate": "utchours(datum.date)", "as": "hoursDate"},
    {
      "calculate": "0 < datum.hoursDate && datum.hoursDate < 7 ? '1 am - 6 am': 6 < datum.hoursDate && datum.hoursDate < 13 ? '7 am - 12 pm' : 12 < datum.hoursDate && datum.hoursDate < 19 ? '1 pm - 6 pm': '7 pm - 12 am'",
      "as": "timeGroup"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.timeGroup == '1 am - 6 am' ? 0 : datum.timeGroup == '7 am - 12 pm' ? 1 : datum.timeGroup == '1 pm - 6 pm' ? 2 : 3",
      "as": "orderRank"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "timeGroup",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "sort": {"field": "orderRank", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "sort": null
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rect"},
      "encoding": {
        "fill": {
          "field": "temperature", "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "mean"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the only thing missing from this answer might be the mean, but we can add it like this: {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "temperature", "type": "quantitative"}

Comment: You can add the additions however you want, but the question was asked for how you will create the bins having groups `6am - 11am' and as such. So my answer was for that.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the vega-lite documentation again, I think I stumbled into an answer that looks good.

Try it in the editor: [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICCNsRpwIUmfIC+SzNqSyIAMzbaEaANqgXNQZhw2migTsrevuaC4egAkgCyACIAQgAEAEpqNLJkiiDESMIxDgxwdpFw0frpbNhwsqkAKmzImGwWGVk5eQVFaCVlALo2NoNKyNoA1vracFCYeQDuNMr0aADMAAybSvA0ZFhoAEzbSvVQbMrZuZogAB4hIEzZj8h3z85oAGybdiB+lRiIASKU6mGueUwAE8cHB9ABHBhOcHqcGkEB-KGPD6vJDvbIQNAAFl+SgBVXQNTqDWarXaEDBEPsMLh6ERyLoWXRfwugncjyQZDIswogX0CDgTjy5KBAHV3NFlso4KkAOLaNgQQnM2EIpGyFFcuEjJQXWR+G6gMxwRaPCAONiTVkgBxOCA4JCzA0YkZAA)

Here's the figure:

[image: Heatmap where each cell shows a mean value.]

And the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {"field": "IMDB Rating", "valid": true},
          {"field": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating", "valid": true}
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "mark": "rect",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 200,
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "bin": {"maxbins": 60},
      "field": "IMDB Rating",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "bin": {"maxbins": 40},
      "field": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "color": {
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "field": "Worldwide Gross",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  },
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}
```

And the link to documentation about how to use `"aggregate"`:

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/aggregate.html#aggregate-op-def